# PHP headers to stream a wmv video file

Tags: php, header, video-streaming, wmv

When I point directly to the file it plays in the browser, but if I try to play it through PHP it does not work. My code is:

```
<?php
$file = 'videos/video.wmv';
$file_name = 'video.wmv';
$file_type = 'video/x-ms-wmv';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: filename="'.$file_name.'"');
header('Content-Type: '.$file_type);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header('Expires: 0');
readfile($file);
?>
```

It works fine with PDF, rar and zip files, but not on streaming video. The WMP window appears but the video dont plays.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Side note: You claim you accept ranges, but the code you show isn't really equipped to handle a range request... either way, why pass this through PHP in the first place? Can you not serve it directly through the web server, which is much more resource friendly?

Comment: Well I'll write a user verification in a DB before print the file. That's whi I need it. And yes, it download other files nice.